# Authorized WebAPI HttpPost endpoint not getting called with HttpWebRequest - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am  facing a strange on one of my web API controllers which is tagged with `System.Web.Http.Authorize`. I have two methods on this API (one `GET` and other `POST`)

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("highestbid/{auctionId}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetHighestBid(string auctionId)
```

And post one is

```
[Route("placeauctionbid")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PlaceAuctionBid([FromBody]BidViewModel bid)
```

My api controller is defined like

```
[RoutePrefix("api/liveauction")]
[System.Web.Http.Authorize]
public class LiveAuctionController : BaseApiController
```

Now my user is authorized and when I call my `HttpGET` with `/api/liveauction/highestbid/1a6a46be`it gets called and I have a value in `User.Identity.GetUserId()` but when I call my `HttpPOST` endpoint api using `HttpWebRequest` it throws an exception

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

When I drill down the WebException response, I see

> IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.15 - Not Found
>   Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the query string is too long.

I am posting data in the body of the request. **Now, if I add `[AllowAnonymous]` on the POST function, with same implementation it gets called** with correct data. User is logged in in both the cases, what might be causing this behavior?

Edit: Adding Request Function (I wrote this generic request manager function for get/post requests)

```
public static ResponseMessage<T> ExecuteRequest<T>(string url, RequestMethod method, string body = null) where T : class
{
    ResponseMessage<T> reponse = new ResponseMessage<T>();
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = method.ToString();
    httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
    if (method == RequestMethod.Post && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(body);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
    }

    try
    {
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        reponse.HttpStatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode;
        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            if (responseStream != null)
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    reponse.Data = Utility.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException webException)
    {
        reponse.Exception = webException;
        reponse.ExceptionStatus = webException.Status;
    }
    return reponse;
}
```

And I am calling it like:

```
ResponseMessage<BidViewModel> apiResponse = RequestManager.ExecuteRequest<BidViewModel>(url, RequestMethod.Post, Utility.SerializeObject(bid));
```

Comment: Show example of request being sent. something may be appending a query string that may be causing the issue.

Comment: @Nkosi I have added the request function, it was a little big so i thought to not include it in original question. :)

Comment: Inspect the raw request sent to the server. fiddle or wire shark should be able to help.